# Error converting string to datetime in Delphi FireMonkey XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, tdatetime

I have a problem when converting a string to TDateTime in FireMonkey , in mobile devices.

It always gives me error and do not know how to do.

I show you what I do:

```
function StringToDateTime(DateStr: String): TDateTime;
var
  FS: TFormatSettings;
begin
  result := now;
  FS:= TFormatSettings.Create;
  FS.DateSeparator := '-';
  FS.DateSeparator := ':';
  FS.ShortDateFormat := 'dd-mm-yyyy';
  FS.ShortTimeFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';
  try
   Result := StrToDateTime(DateStr, FS); //the format of the string is : 
         // dd-mm-yyyy hh:nn:ss  '31-03-2015 9:36:00'
  except on E: Exception do
   ShowMessage(e.ToString);
  end;

end;
```

The exception is giving:

> '31-03-2015 9:36:00' is not a valid date and time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion with StrToDateTime and TFormatSettings does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308472/conversion-with-strtodatetime-and-tformatsettings-does-not-work)

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Use `FS.TimeSeparator := ':';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring `DateSeparator` twice

```
  FS.DateSeparator := '-';
  FS.TimeSeparator := ':';
```

Comment: Thanks , I feel ashamed , sorry .
I have been a good time analyzing the code and neither have I noticed.
Sorry.

Comment: If you want to delete the question feel free to do so. I will not mind :)